# Munin output in json rather than in graphs

Tags: linux, statistics, munin

I want to use munin to collect system stats and save it in database. But I could not find any way to get the raw stats munin collects. Is there any way to get that raw data munin collects and with which it creates graph ?

Comment: Munin team pushes an update about once a month. There is now a mention of JSON API, which may change the answer to this question. If you figure it out, please add a fully-fledged answer. From http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki: 2014-05-05: Munin 2.1.7 is released. Unstable version that is using SQL for internal states. First release of the JSON API.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to access the historical data using the `rrdtool` command, e.g. using something like `rrdtool fetch /var/munin/{domain}/{something}.rrd AVERAGE` (this is the path of the data files on FreeBSD systems, on Linux it may be /var/lib/munin or so).

Answer (score 0):

You can export munin (or rather the underlying rrdtool) data in xml format using

```
rrdtool xport \
      --start now-1h --end now \
      DEF:xx=host-inout.lo.rrd:output:AVERAGE \
      DEF:yy=host-inout.lo.rrd:input:AVERAGE \
      CDEF:aa=xx,yy,+,8,* \
      XPORT:xx:"out bytes" \
      XPORT:aa:"in and out bits"
```

The resulting meta data section is (the values will depend on the RRD characteristics):

```
<meta>
<start>1020611700</start>
<step>300</step>
<end>1020615600</end>
<rows>14</rows>
<columns>2</columns>
<legend>
  <entry>out bytes</entry>
  <entry>in and out bits</entry>
</legend>
```

The resulting data section is:

```
<data>
<row><t>1020611700</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020612000</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020612300</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020612600</t><v>3.4113333333e+00</v><v>5.4581333333e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020612900</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020613200</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020613500</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020613800</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020614100</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020614400</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020614700</t><v>3.7333333333e+00</v><v>5.9733333333e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020615000</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020615300</t><v>3.4000000000e+00</v><v>5.4400000000e+01</v></row>
<row><t>1020615600</t><v>NaN</v><v>NaN</v></row>
```

I use the xml export to generate charts using JavaScript for my home temperature monitoring at http://pi.tafkas.net/temperatures/

Answer (score -1):

Munin relies on its plugins to gather the stats.  Although the plugins can be written in just about any language, the majority are scripts of some sort (shell, Perl, Python, etc.).  Take a look at each plugin (that you want to use) to see how the data is gathered.  You should be able to write your own, and cron it (just as munin does) so that it grabs a metric every 5 minutes (or however long you want).

You'll probably need to write additional scripts to aggregate data as you graph some of the larger data sets (e.g., graphing an entire year's data).   That and/or scripts to get rid of data after a certain time period.

Comment: On Ubuntu systems, the plugins are in /usr/lib/munin/plugins.